# What do they mean in flutter by 'cross axis'?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I see in the flutter layout docs the term 'cross axis' all over the place.  Does this mean for a vertical layout scheme the horizontal axis is the cross axis, while in a horizontal one it's the vertical axis?  Or is it more complicated than that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a column the main axis is vertical and the cross axis is horizontal (90° to the main axis).
For a row the main axis is horizontal and the cross axis is vertical (90° to the main axis).

Answer (score 39):

`MainAxis` is the axis for the Widget in which it is supposed to scroll.

`CrossAxis` is the one which is perpendicular to MainAxis.

---

**For Row:**

`mainAxisAlignment` = Horizontal Axis
`crossAxisAlignment` = Vertical Axis

[image]

---

**For Column:**

`mainAxisAlignment` = Vertical Axis
`crossAxisAlignment` = Horizontal Axis

[image]

[Image source](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout#aligning-widgets)