# Flutter | Text position inside of card

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently coding a timer on Flutter here's my code and screenshoot. I'm pretty new to flutter but every fix I tried to this don't work.

[image: THE APP UI]

And here's my code:

```
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              left: 20,
              right: 20,
              child: Card(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(44, 47, 93, 1),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                child: InkWell(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 342,
                    height: 344,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            'POMODORO',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white, 
                                fontFamily: 'SFPro',
                                fontSize: 12
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            'SHORT BREAK',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white, 
                                fontFamily: 'SFPro',
                                fontSize: 12
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            'LONG BREAK',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white, 
                                fontFamily: 'SFPro',
                                fontSize: 12
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ], // Children
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ], // Children
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I  have a question:

1. How can I move the 3 Pomodoro, Short Break and Long Break to the top of the card?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: better to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52709002/what-do-they-mean-in-flutter-by-cross-axis#:~:text=CrossAxis%20is%20the%20one%20which%20is%20perpendicular%20to%20MainAxis.&text=is%20not%20useful-,Show%20activity%20on%20this%20post.,%C2%B0%20to%20the%20main%20axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` in the Row plus add a `padding` to `SizedBox` as follows

```
SizedBox(
                    
                    width: 342,
                    height: 344,
                    child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Row(
                      
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            'POMODORO',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white, 
                                fontFamily: 'SFPro',
                                fontSize: 12
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            'SHORT BREAK',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white, 
                                fontFamily: 'SFPro',
                                fontSize: 12
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            'LONG BREAK',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white, 
                                fontFamily: 'SFPro',
                                fontSize: 12
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ], // Children
                    ),)
                  ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` as your Row's property.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to leave a bit of top margin?

Comment: The simplest way to achieve it is to simply wrap a Row widget with `Padding` widget and specify its `padding` property :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers already, you want to consider the AxisAlignment.
When your widgets are inside a Row the MainAxis is horizontal and traversed from left to right.
When the are inside a Column the MainAxis is vertical and traversed from top to bottom.
The CrossAxisAlignment considers the opposite of the MainAxisAlignment of the Row/Column.

You can now adjust the positions of the Widgets in the Row/Column by setting the Main/Cross AxisAlignment.